# Do I need to download whole blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

Im using bitcoin core debian linux to process payments on my shop using RPC API calls. 
Now im switching wallet server, do I need to download whole block chain in order to process transactions on my shop? like create addresses for customers, see balance for customers,,,etc

Comment: What does it mean "Now I'm switching wallet server") if you change the machine server you can copy the .bitcoin dir in the new server if I understand well

Comment: Important to note the new server will still need to resync and reverify which takes a considerable amount of time even if you already have downloaded all the blocks.